# Import database from File PROGRAMMATICALLY?

Tags: sql, database, csv, import

Is there a way to programatically import an entire database from a file with SQL?? (either .CSV , .SQL and .DB files are fine)

Thanks!!

EDITED AFTER TO CLARIFY:

I am interested in a solution that is Database independent (has to works with all types of databases (Mysql, SQL Server, PostGres, Oracle...)

Comment: @Giorgio, which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: The question is not yet comprehensive. What database are you talking about? Oracle supports SQL loader and SQL Server also supports similar tool.

Comment: Once we know the database flavour this question will almost certainly be a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: That's really the point!
Is there a solution that is Database Independent!?

Anyway I'm using Sqlite as Database and Java as programming language, if you know a solution for this combination tell me anyway!
THANKS!!

Comment: "Is there a solution that is Database Independent!?" The answer to that is NO.

Comment: Thanks Jason S that's what I wanted to know!!

It's too bad there isn't a standard in SQL to import/export databases cause in this way each type of database has to define its own way...

Comment: Jason S I found a solution that is Database independent!
Check the 4th answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I actually found a solution that is Database INDEPENDENT to import a database from a .Sql file quite easily!! :)

So whichever database you have (Mysql, Sqlite, ...) do the following:

1) export your database into .sql format. 
(This .sql file will contain all sql commands such as CREATE TABLE... INSERT INTO table...)
(You may need to remove the lines that start with CREATE TABLE and leave only the lines that start with INSERT...)

2) Then in the language that you are using write some code that read each line of the Sql Lite files and stores it into an Array of String (String[])

3) Then execute each String contained in the array String[] as sql command

I've implemented this in Java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
```

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DatabaseImporter {

`private static DatabaseImporter instance;

public static DatabaseImporter getInstance(){
    if(DatabaseImporter.instance == null)
        instance = new DatabaseImporter();

    return DatabaseImporter.instance;
}

private DatabaseImporter (){

}

public void importDatabaseFromFile(Context context, String databaseName , String filePath){

    SQLiteDatabase database = //CREATE UR DATABASE WITH THE COMMAND FROM THE DATABASE API YOUR USING

    this.executeSqlCommands(    database                                , 
                                this.readSqlCommandsFromFile(filePath)
                            );
}


private String[] readSqlCommandsFromFile(String filePath){

    String[] sqlCommands = new String[0];
    List<String> sqlCommandsList = new LinkedList<String>();

    try{

        // Open the file that is the first 
        // command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine;
        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            if(!strLine.equals("") && !strLine.equals(" ") && strLine != null)
                sqlCommandsList.add(strLine);
        }
        //Close the input stream
        in.close();

    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    sqlCommands = new String[sqlCommandsList.size()];

    sqlCommandsList.toArray(sqlCommands);

    return sqlCommands;
}


private void executeSqlCommands(SQLiteDatabase database, String[] sqlCommands){

    for(int i = 0; i < sqlCommands.length ; i++){


        database.execSQL(sqlCommands[i]);
    }
}`

}

Comment: That's not database independent, that's for SQLite.

Comment: The approach is database independent and only the snippet of code is database specific

Answer (score 3):

MySQL: [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) for csv's; for .sql files generated with MySQL, use the shell.

---

For SQLite: see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697004/bulk-load-data-into-sqlite).

SQL Server: apparently there's the [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) command.

You are not going to find a database-independent syntax for an SQL command because there isn't one.

There may be a wrapper library around databases but I'm not aware of it. (Or you could try to use ODBC, but that's connection oriented and wouldn't allow direct access to a file)

Perhaps there is an interactive GUI-related software tool out there to do this.

Note also that loading data directly from a file on a database server into a database almost certainly requires security privileges to do so (otherwise it is a security risk).

Comment: Hey! I want to do that programatically inside of the code!
I need to write an algorithm that each time imports a different database file so I can't type commands in the shell

Answer (score 1):

mysql -u  -p < dumpfile.sql

importing csv would require a script (using eg. PHP) to put the right fields in the right bit of the query.

Comment: Is this command part of PHP or is part of Mysql and has to be inserted into the command line shell?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server check out [SSIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)