# Inserting CSV data to SQLite in PHP PDO - is there any faster method than insert row by row?

Tags: php, sqlite, insert, pdo, bulk

Im looking for **efficient method** for inserting CSV data into SQLite database on remote server.

I have to use PHP. Im using SQLite3, so i have to use PDO (sqlite_query will not work).

CSV is on server side and it has 100000+ rows (50MB+ filesize).

**Question: is there any method for PHP faster than this?**

```
for (/* each row, 100.000 rows */)
{
    $a = 'something';
    $b = 'something';
    $query = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info (a, b) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $query->bindParam(1, $a);
    $query->bindParam(2, $b);
    $query->execute();
}
```

My SQL file is in the same directory.

I've read about `.import` command, but **i don't know how to use it with PDO** (shall i use `prepare`? how file path should look like?).

Im new to PDO and SQLite.

Comment: Read it, then write it. Whats the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bulk load data into sqlite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697004/bulk-load-data-into-sqlite)

Comment: @KingCrunch its not duplicate .. what if you need to filter invalid values ??? The link you gave can only work for trusted values

Comment: @Baba That would be something different, but the question doesn't contain a "filter", it contains oly a "inserting a CSV into SQLite database". Also the OP mentioned mentioned `.import` himself. If you are right, the OP should clarify his question, else it's a duplicate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know if there is a bulk approach with SQLite that can be used via a PDO driver, but you are re-preparing the same statement on every loop.

This would probably be a touch more efficient:

```
$query = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info (a, b) VALUES (?, ?)");
for (/* each row, 100.000 rows */)
{
    $a = 'something';
    $b = 'something';

    $query->bindParam(1, $a);
    $query->bindParam(2, $b);
    $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: Right. And what about arrays? I have array like this: $data[$row][$cell]. Can I bind array element somehow? I mean dynamic row index. I had problems with binding array elements in C# and MSSQL, and i didn't used array here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
$link->beginTransaction();

$query = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info (a, b) VALUES (?, ?)");
for (/* each row, 100.000 rows */)
{
//variable stuff + execute query
}

$link->commit();
```

This holds the writes until after the loop - much faster.
You'll need to create db object like this:
    $link = new PDO('sqlite:your.db');

edit: Typo/paste correction

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that this may not produce the same speed-up on other DB systems - in fact, quite the opposite, since the DBMS will have to maintain a higher isolation level, and either acquire a lock or maintain a temporary version of the data.