# sqlite load data infile Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sqlite, csv

I'm working on importing a very large CSV file into SQLite. My understanding is that **`LOAD DATA INFILE`** is my best bet.  I've created a table for it to reside in, and am attempting to execute the following query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'F:/Downloads/NielsonReport.csv' 
INTO TABLE neilson;
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

but, I get the following error:

```
Error while executing SQL query on database 'test': near "LOAD": syntax error
```

I seem to be getting an error along these lines regardless of what I'm trying to execute.

I feel like I'm missing something very basic, and would appreciate any help resolving this problem (I've been referencing [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) for information so far)

Comment: Try removing the semicolon...

Comment: No change when doing that.  I've tried a few permuations in case i was properly or improperly using semicolons to mark off items.

Comment: Question...are you trying to load the csv file into `sqlite` or `mysql`?

Comment: Trying to load into SQLite

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697004/bulk-load-data-into-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

When you are using SQLite, it would be a good idea to reference the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) instead.

Anyway, SQLite itself does not have a CSV import function. But the [`sqlite3` command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv) allows to import CSV files with the `.import` command.

Answer (score -1):

Use ***import*** command like this.

```
.import '/Users/haseeb/Desktop/names_data.txt' Names
```